# Change Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME to always be 1

Tags: clock, date-and-time, time-zones

I want my android apps to believe that Automatic Time Zone is set to ON even though it actually is not. I read that Automatic Time Zone is detected using Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME variable, which returns value 1 if Automatic Time Zone is ON and value 0 if Automatic Time Zone is OFF. This variable is read using the below line

```
Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME)
```

I read that this variable can only be set by a System App. Is there a way to change this variable somehow? Can I write an application that allows me to change this variable? Can this be done by rooting the android device? Is there a way to do this without rooting?

Answer (score 0):

Since the phone is rooted, it would be possible for an Xposed module to achieve this by intercepting the call to `Settings.Global.getInt` and returning 1 regardless of the real value, but I don't know of a module that does this, so you'd have to write it yourself. You should consult the Xposed documentation to learn how; I'm afraid we can't help with programming problems on this site.